# CaptureStackBackTrace inconsistencies using FramesToSkip

Tags: c, winapi, stack-trace

On windows you can capturing the stack trace using [CaptureStackBackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633(v=vs.85).aspx) as

```
void* frames[USHRT_MAX];
USHORT framesCount = CaptureStackBackTrace(0, USHRT_MAX, frames, NULL);
```

However, capturing it by smaller chunks in a loop to avoid allocating a `USHRT_MAX` buffer doesn't provide the same result.

This code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(noinline) void CheckStack(void)
{
    printf("Checking stack...\n");

    void* entireStack[USHRT_MAX];
    USHORT frameCount = CaptureStackBackTrace(0, USHRT_MAX, entireStack, NULL);

    printf("Stack size is: %u\n", frameCount);

    ULONG frameOffset = 1;

    for (;;)
    {
        void* chunk[64];
        USHORT framesFound = CaptureStackBackTrace(frameOffset, 64, chunk, NULL);
        if (framesFound)
        {
            if (memcmp(entireStack + frameOffset, chunk, sizeof(chunk)) != 0)
            {
                printf("Incorrect content\n");
            }

            frameOffset += (ULONG)framesFound; 
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (frameCount != frameOffset)
    {
        printf("Incorrect count (%u != %u)\n", frameCount, frameOffset);
    }

    printf("Done\n");
}

__declspec(noinline) void Test(int i)
{
    if (i != 500)
        Test(++i);
    else
        CheckStack();
}

int main()
{
    Test(0);
}
```

produces the following output

```
Checking stack...
Stack size is: 507
Incorrect count (507 != 257)
Done
```

when building as `cl /Od main.c /link /OUT:main.exe`.

Am I using the `FramesToSkip` parameter incorrectly or why are the counts not equal?

Comment: api check `FramesToSkip ` and if `FramesToSkip > 254` just return 0. as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP,

> The sum of the FramesToSkip and FramesToCapture parameters must be
>   less than 63.

That's in document.

Else, as @RbMm says, In the API source code, there is the following logic:

```
if(FramesToSkip>0xfe)
{
    return 0;  //There are too many stack structures skipped, returning directly to 0.
}
```

However, this is not metioned on msdn both in the [CaptureStackBackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [RtlCaptureStackBackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-rtlcapturestackbacktrace).
I am not going to post the source code here, but prove it in debugging:

1.Create a sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(noinline) void CheckStack(void)
{
    void* entireStack[USHRT_MAX];
    USHORT frameCount = CaptureStackBackTrace(255, USHRT_MAX, entireStack, NULL);
}

__declspec(noinline) void Test(int i)
{
    if (i != 500)
        Test(++i);
    else
        CheckStack();
}

int main()
{
    Test(0);
}
```

2. Step into `CaptureStackBackTrace` in Disassembly:
[image]
You can see that `dword ptr[ebp+8]`(the first parameter of `CaptureStackBackTrace` pushed in stack) will be compared with `0feh`(254). If true, return 0.

Comment: Seems very strange that this is not documented, I'll file a bug report to Microsoft.

Comment: @JensÅkerblom Agree, and could you send me an issue link after reporting?

Comment: @Drakw Wu - MSFT Bug report is here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/548661/passing-framestoskip-greater-than-254-to-rtlcaptur.html